# CSS: overflow-y and padding adjustment

Tags: css, overflow, padding

Hi I am trying to pad some text with over-flow and padding but the bottom padding does not work like the rest of the top, left and right borders.

I try adding text-overflow but this didn't work. :(

I want to see the word "TEST" to be partially hidden, and not touching the black border.

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.css {
 width: 220px;
 height: 220px;
 border: solid 6px black;
 font-size: 45pt;
 padding: 10px 17px;
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 90%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color:red;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-overflow:'';
}
```

```html
<div class="css">CSS IS AWESOME TEST</div>
```

https://codepen.io/StoptThisRetard/pen/eRrrJg

Comment: Post your tried code.

Comment: Adjust css height or use overflow-y: scroll

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `overflow:hidden` hides the content that goes **outside** the box, whereas `padding` is **inside** the box.

So what result you are getting, is correct.

To solve your issue, you can add another div and give that div padding and background. See snippet below

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.css {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  font-size: 45pt;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 90%;
  
   overflow: hidden;
}

.css_wrapper {
  padding: 10px 17px;
  border: solid 6px black;
  background-color: red;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="css_wrapper">
  <div class="css">CSS IS AWESOME TEST</div>
</div>
```